# Slow loading when data more than 1000

Tags: php, laravel, performance

**The issue is that my laravel application speed's is too slow when the result has over 7k rows.**

It keep loading for at 23 seconds or more to show the data in a table (i'm using bootstrap model of datatable)

**System details:**
PHP Version 8.0.2
Laravel Version 9.11

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Why do you want to show 7k rows in a single table? Why not paginate the results?

Comment: i've tried to paginate the result like this
`$file = File::orderBy('date', 'DESC')->paginate(10);`
but i'm using bootstrap datatable to paginate and make search so this solution is not applicable for my case.
and i want to show 7k rows because its the data that i would to show it in the same table.

**My Controller**
`public function list(){
$file = File::orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get();
return view('welcome' , compact('file'));
}`

**Blade**
`@foreach($file as $key=>$f)
      //call to attributes
@endforeach`

Comment: thank you in advance and sorry for my english mistakes.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: This is because you try to load 7k rows. Your only solution is paginating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used paginate in my **controller** in this way :

```
public function list(){
$file = File::orderBy('date', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
return view('welcome' , compact('file'));
}
```

and i add this line in **Blade** :

```
{{ $file->links() }}
```

and it works at 702ms

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can use [Cache](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache) and [Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination) to solve this problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).